# How to transfer String from one class to another in Java

Tags: java, string, class

I have these two classes:

ConnectionPanel.class

```
public class ConnectionPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener,ItemListener, PropertyChangeListener {
   private MasterModel m_masterModel;
   private JTextField m_keyField;

   public ConnectionPanel(MasterModel masterModel) {
       m_masterModel = masterModel;
       setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
       JPanel panel = null;
       panel = new JPanel();
       panel.add(new JLabel("Type Key:"));
       m_keyField = new JTextField(9);
       m_keyField.setText("dertfgdertabcdef");
       panel.add(m_keyField);
       add(panel);
       getChatModel().addPropertyChangeListener(this);
       getChatModel().setListen(true);
    } 

    public String getEncryptionKey(){
       return m_keyField.getText();
    }
}
```

AudioPlayback.class

```
public class AudioPlayback extends AudioBase {
    // and here I want to be able to get
    // somehow String key = ConnectionPanel.getEncryptionKey()
    // I tried ConnectionPanel panel = new ConnectionPanel(); but does not work
    // it messes my graphical interface
    // also there is lots of code here too
}
```

Do you have any ideas how can I get that field input into my audioplayback.class ?

Comment: Do you know the basics of classes, variables and keywords in Java?

Comment: I have rarely used multiple classes, most of my applications were procedural this is why I am confronting with this problem.

Comment: Then I suggest have a look at some tutorials about how to use classes, if you want to make a application with it.

Comment: I second @moffeltje - this is a very basic java syntax / OO design issue, and probably not suitable for stack overflow.  In this case your AudioPlayback needs to get a reference ConnectoinPanel

Comment: I'm sorry, I know that this question may be simple but I do not even know where to look for the answer. I would appreciate if you can suggest any link to find the answer to this.

Comment: @CatalinBcn Check this [popular site](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20classes%20tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with moffeltje & Luke. This question is simple so that I think you can learn something more basic on Java.
But I review your constructor of ConnectionPanel.Excuse me, do you know constructor?
You can find the details here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Now, let's talk about your code. You only give a constructor with one input parameter to ConnectionPanel so that you can't use the constructor without parameters in AudioPlayback.
But the attribute masterModel seems hasn't been called in your ConnectionPanel so that you can roughly use the following code:

```
// Notice! Don't do this in your production enviroment. It's only for test otherwise you can make sure that you can give the null value to it.
ConnectionPanel panle = new ConnectionPanel(null);
System.out.println(panel.getEncryptionKey());
```